# Different approaches to unit test method definition?

Tags: apex, unit-test

When working on unit tests in apex, what's the difference between the following code snippets?

```
static testMethod void myTest() {
//
}
```

and

```
@isTest
static void myTest() {
//
}
```

Are they just different approaches to method definition or is there more to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [@IsTest documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm) they are equivalent, and no benefit or prefered syntax is mentioned.

I suspect the `testMethod` keyword was first, and that they needed an alternative that could take the `SeeAllData` parameter when hiding your actual data from tests by default.

> For Apex code saved using Salesforce.com API version 24.0 and later, use the isTest(SeeAllData=true) annotation to grant test classes and individual test methods access to all data in the organization, including pre-existing data that the test didn’t create.

So I expect the isTest annotation didn't exist before API 24.0.